# How to set up and dereference a generic pointer for a derived class object for an expression parser?

Tags: c++, parsing, pointers, templates, generics

I could not find a solution to the following problem -
I have a base class

```
class foo{
public:
   foo *lhs, *rhs;
   foo() {}
};
```

I derive a templated class :-

```
template <typename T> 
class bar : public foo {
    public:
    T x;
    bar(x){this->x = x;}
}
```

Then I do the following -

```
void main(void)
{
  bar <std::string> *x1 = new bar<std::string> ("Avogadro");
  bar <double>      *x2 = new bar<double> v(6.023e23);
  foo               *x3 = new foo;  /*create a pointer of type base class*/

 /*and point the lhs and rhs pointers to the derived class objects*/
 x3->lhs = x1;
 x3->rhs = x2;
}
```

What I would like to do is eventually dereference the generic pointer to get to the derived class objects. Like this -

```
x3->lhs->x and 
x3->rhs->x
```

Is this how generic pointers work ? And if so why do I get the segmentation fault? If you are wondering, I am trying to create a parse tree in C++....

Comment: What's with all the `new` and unnecessary pointers (in `main`)? The segfault is because you haven't created an `*x3` object to set the `lhs` and `rhs` of!

Comment: Remove the asterisk before `x3`

Comment: Thanks to you both! I see the error and have fixed the segmentation fault. But my question generally is that - is there a way to access objects of the derived class using pointers of type base class ? If not what is the proper way to construct a tree with leaves of different types and be able to traverse it using templated classes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to access objects of the derived class using pointers of type base class?

Yes, it is called a downcast. You usually want to avoid it since it needs you to store type information about each object, which defeats the purpose of upcasting to the base class in the first place. It can be done by `dynamic_cast`.

> What is the proper way to construct a tree with leaves of different types and be able to traverse it using templated classes ?

Using inheritance is not the best way to approach this. Inheritance is best used when different classes need to interact with the same interface. In this case, you could use an `std::variant` (C++17).

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
class foo{
public:
   using value_type = std::variant<foo, std::string, double>;
   value_type *lhs, *rhs;
};

int main()
{
  std::string x1 = "Avogadro";
  double x2 = 6.023e23;
  foo x3;
  x3.lhs = new foo::value_type(x1);
  x3.rhs = new foo::value_type(x2);

  // 1: visitor pattern                                                                                                                  
  std::visit([](auto&& arg) {
    using T = std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>;
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) {
      std::cout << "string is " << arg << std::endl;
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>) {
      std::cout << "double is " << arg << std::endl;
    } else {
      std::cout << "Not a leaf" << std::endl;
    }
  }, *x3.lhs);

  // 2: get index                                                                                                                        
  switch (x3.rhs->index()) {
  case 0: std::cout << "Not a leaf" << std::endl; break;
  case 1: std::cout << "string is " << std::get<1>(*x3.rhs) << std::endl; break;
  case 2: std::cout << "double is " << std::get<2>(*x3.rhs) << std::endl; break;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
string is Avogadro 
double is 6.023e+23
```

Comment: Thanks Kostas! This is exactly what I was looking for and yes, no issues storing they types as they are know in advance.